# AutoSuggest in a asp.net using Ajax controls toolkit and passing values to array

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

THis is Page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if
            (Session["useremail"] == null) Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        else
        {
            Label8.Text = Session["useremail"].ToString();
        }
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender.ContextKey = Label8.Text;
        }
    }
```

Now I have stored the session useremail in TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender.ContextKey.

How to use pass the TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender.ContextKey value to a variable in the below method.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
    public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
    {

        string[] movies = { "Joey", "Joester", "Joker", "Joeic", "Joic", "Shrek II" };


        return (from m in movies where m.StartsWith(prefixText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) select m).Take(count).ToArray();
    }
```

Instead of passing that array value predefined I want to pass a column from the database table user (column name is firstname) i can filter it only with the email id value. Please help

Comment: I'm confused. Can you post some code showing how you're calling the GetCompletionList method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by enabling session state in your web service which contains the GetCompletionList(...) method so that you can access the user's email address in the same fashion as in your ASP.NET Web application / site.

By default, session support is turned off for a web method. You must explicitly enable it for each web method by setting the EnableSession property of the WebMethod attribute to true. When enabled you can access the session state in the same manner as you are accustomed to in ASP.NET.

For example:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true), ScriptMethod()]
public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string 
    contextKey)
{ 
   var useremail = Session["useremail"] ?? null;
   //...
}
```

More information on the EnableSession property of the WebMethodAttribute can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.enablesession.aspx

Be aware that if the clients (consumers) of your web service use cookies to maintain the session state, that they must support HTTP cookies. Should be no problem for modern browsers (which I assume are your main clients).

More information needed about using ASP.NET Session in a web service? Just go to the following link on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480509.aspx

Comment: I am getting this error --> An object reference is required for the non static field,method or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Session.Get'

Comment: Could you copy/paste the line of code that is throwing this error and maybe a bit more information in which context this line is being called.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if
            (Session["useremail"] == null) Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        else
        {
            Label8.Text = Session["useremail"].ToString();
        }
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender.ContextKey = Label8.Text;
        }
    }

Comment: [WebMethod(EnableSession = true), ScriptMethod()]
public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string 
    contextKey)
{ 
   var useremail = Session["useremail"].ToString();
 
}